# Expired Israel passport with expired American visa thrown out last year

Tags: israeli-citizens, us-visa

My husband, after having a stroke cleaned his drawers and got rid of things he didn't need anymore.

He threw out his expired Israeli passport which had an expired American visa in it. Now applying for a new visa to enter America we see that one of the questions is did he have a visa already, and the numbers, dates, etc

We don't have that information anymore, so couldn't proceed with reapplying for a new visa.

How do we solve this problem. I have a photocopy of his old passport with the number, can the information be recruited from there, so we can proceed.

Also after my husbands stroke, he has aphasia, which he is not capable of speaking, writing and reading. Can I go with him to the embassy?

Comment: Typically, you'd answer "yes" to "did you have a visa", and write "unknown" for the questions about the visa number, etc.

Comment: The  other question you need to ask yourself is would the USA normally approve a visa for someone who probably needs significant medical attention? Concerning the missing visa, USA has all that information in their system and will pull it out once they have his name and birthdate.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course go with him to his visa interview at the embassy, and if you explain why you can also answer for him.
He might have to agree (visibly) to have you speak for him, if he is capable of that. If he is not able to confirm for you, you may need a medical declaration of his problems.
It will also be good to have proof of your relationship, if you have it.

In regard of the information you do no longer have, enter yes for having had a visa, enter what you have for the numbers and enter 'unknown' for the rest.